# Displaying Items Based On HTML 5 Checkbox Input

Tags: javascript, html

If I have two HTML 5 checkboxes like these...

```
<input name="your_name" value="your_value1" type="checkbox">

<input name="your_name2" value="your_value2" type="checkbox">
```

How can I display a textarea (or any other HTML 5 item) based on the input of the user? For example, if they selected value1 show one block of text, if they selected value2 show a different block of text. What would be the best way to do this, without having to reload the page or submit a form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the elements are siblings, the simplest approach would be to use the `:checked` pseudo class to determine if the checkbox is checked. Then you can use the general sibling selector, `~`, to select the following sibling element(s) depending on the checked state:

```css
[name="your_name"]:checked ~ .block1 {
  display: block;
}
[name="your_name2"]:checked ~ .block2 {
  display: block;
}
p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="your_name" value="your_value1" type="checkbox">
<input name="your_name2" value="your_value2" type="checkbox">

<p class="block1">Block 1</p>
<p class="block2">Block 2</p>
```

If you want to go the JavaScript route, you would need to attach a `change` event listener to the checkbox element.

For instance:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[name="your_name"]'),
    text = document.querySelector('.text');

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  text.style.display = e.target.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<input name="your_name" value="your_value1" type="checkbox">

<p class="text" style="display: none">Block 1</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is an amazing example!